# Why Visual Studio Code did not highlight 'this.***' unused variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If writing in Visual Studio code you make a mistake it is often highlighted:

[image]

Visual Studio code does detect:

- wrong class name (NotMyClass)
- wrong local variable (pp2)
- wrong function name (rect)

But it does not detect anything wrong if it starts with "this". In particular "this.p3" does not exist. And even when I open the site in the browser (after fixing other mistakes) it executes "well" and instead of "this.p3" I get (I assume?) 0 and no any error log...

Why is it so? Any chance teaching it to highlight this mistake?

P.S. I'm from C#.NET world and relatively new to JS/TS so please educate if I miss something basic.

Comment: Well when the function is actually called, `this.p3` *might* exist. It's not possible for it to be certain that it won't.

Comment: Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Also don't build prototype properties in a constructor.

Comment: Notice that it's not VS Code detecting this itself, but rather a linter you enabled for that language

Comment: You want static type-safety. You tag `typescript`. You program in vanilla JS. You don't get static type-safety. You complain. What?

Comment: You've tagged your question with "TypeScript", but apparently you're not using it yet. If you did, the plugin *would* complain about the missing `.p3` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ASDFGerte is right, it is indeed JS ... I made JS work inside of Angular application (don't ask why, I'm learning and playing) but forgot this is JS and not everything from TS applies to JS.

I guess the answer is: don't use JS. Thanks all!

P.S. Also, many thanks for other hints

Comment: So one could say this is not reproducible or caused by a typo and was resolved in a way unlikely to help others?